# While True with Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have some problem with, to send data in sqlite3. This is my code:

```
date = raw_input("Enter date: ")

f_name = []
s_name = []

def enter():
    while True:
        f = raw_input("Enter name: ")
        e = raw_input("Enter second name: ")

        if len(f) == 0:
            break
        elif len(e) == 0:
            break
        else:
            a = f
            f_name.append(a)
            y = e
            s_name.append(y)

    zipped = zip(f_name, s_name)

    c.executemany("INSERT INTO test_table(first_name, "
              "second_name, date) VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
              (zipped, date))
    conn.commit()  

create_table()
enter()
conn.close()
```

Only that I need is, while True loop must work until stop, and in each iteration of the loop, send to data: first name, second name and date.

Comment: You never assign anything to `f_name` and `s_name`.

Comment: Why are you zipping the lists? Is that necessary to insert into sqlite?

Comment: So how I can insert into if I will not zipping the lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 2 other `while` loops inside your `while True`, look at the following code:

```
my_date = raw_input("Enter date: ")

f_name = []
s_name = []

def enter():
    while True:
        fn = raw_input("Enter name: ")
        while not fn:  # You do not need to use len(fn) == 0
            fn = raw_input("Enter name: ")

        sn = raw_input("Enter second name: ")
        while not sn:
            sn = raw_input("Enter second name: ")

        f_name.append(fn)
        s_name.append(sn)

    zipped = zip(f_name, s_name)
    zipped = [item + (my_date,) for item in zipped]  # You need to my_date to each item in zipped

    c.executemany("""
        INSERT INTO test_table ('first_name', 'second_name', 'date')
        VALUES(?, ?, ?)""", zipped)
    # ...
```

Comment: error: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 1 supplied

Comment: Work! Thank you for help!